# Error maven : Could not resolve dependencies for project ...

Tags: java, maven, selenium, dependencies

My Maven install is failing when I had a last dependency. This is extent report.
Here is the POM :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>fr.SIRHEN.automation</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <version>6.9.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.fluentlenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>fluentlenium-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>openws</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xom</groupId>
    <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
    <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.samba.jcifs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>rhino</groupId>
    <artifactId>js</artifactId>
    <version>1.7R2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.15.v20160210</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-core-js</artifactId>
    <version>2.23</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.23</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.5</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>central</id>
<name>bintray</name>
<url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
<id>central2</id>
<name>soapui</name>
<url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>

<groupId>fr.SIRHEN</groupId>
<name>AutomatisationSIRHENMAVEN</name>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

And I get the error :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AutomatisationSIRHENMAVEN 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/aventstack/extentreports/3.0.5/extentreports-3.0.5.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/com/aventstack/extentreports/3.0.5/extentreports-3.0.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.637 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-12T14:40:24+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/157M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project fr.SIRHEN.automation: Could not resolve dependencies for project fr.SIRHEN:fr.SIRHEN.automation:jar:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.aventstack:extentreports:jar:3.0.5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.aventstack:extentreports:jar:3.0.5: Could not transfer artifact com.aventstack:extentreports:pom:3.0.5 from/to central (http://central.maven.org/maven2/): central.maven.org: Unknown host central.maven.org -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

And I don't find a way to resolve it.

When I remove this dependency, maven install is working.

Comment: Can you reach central.maven.org from your current host ( the one on wich the maven build is executed)?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand the question...

Comment: ok open a web browser and type in the address bar central.maven.org does it return any thing or 404 ?

Comment: It returns something. A folder maven2 with a lot of subfolders

Comment: how do you start your maven install ?

Comment: In eclipse, right click on my projet > run as > maven install

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141553/discussion-between-nemesis-and-celianou).

Comment: Can you check if other versions of aventstack jars, already exist in your local repository? if exists delete them manually and try doing maven install  again. if it does not exist then try doing maven update and check force updates check box and give it a maven build.

Comment: @Nemesis, my security client don't enable me to chat on your link
Alekhya, there is no other versions... how to force updates check box ?

Comment: Also, try to add following plugin your pom.xml `<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>`

Comment: Why do you have to define a `<repository>` for the central repository at all in your POM? It is part of the super-POM and inherited by any Maven project. At best this is redundant, at worst you’ve introduced an error.

Comment: what is the dependecy that gives you the error? this one?
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>

Comment: any progress on this issue?